# how to fix the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')

Tags: javascript

```
const month=props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month:'long'});
```

the code shows an error with input data but completely works with dummy data
and I have tried other datatype of toLocaleString but its not working

Comment: We need a little bit more info for this. Where do props come from? Right now props.date is undefined and so you can't use toLocaleString method on it.

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `props.date` is `undefined`.  What value do you expect it to have and why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your property data is undefined, try adding a check for the property data

const month= props.date ? props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month:'long'}) : null;